# How does Stability interact with conditions?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have noticed that gaining Armor of Earth does not release a player from an Immobilize condition. But, it does appear to remove the Feared condition. It also appears to make the player stand up after being knocked down, though being knocked down doesn't appear to have any condition attached to it.

How does Stability interact with conditions (or how does it work, in general)?

Comment: I have realized that I was assuming that **[Armor of Earth](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armor_of_Earth)** only applied Stability. It is also a stun breaker. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Immobilize is not really a control like Fear, it is a condition which condition removal and condition duration reduction skills effect. So a Stun breaker or Stability won't do anything. But dodging or blocks will make an immobilisation attack miss or be blocked.

Two things to consider in GW2 stability and stun breakers. You need stability on to negate knock backs, knock downs, fears, stuns.  Blinds are a condition

If you have been CC'd a Stun breaker will break that effect, remembering that Necros can chain fears with their wells and some skills. So in that case you need both.

The other aspect is condition removal, Fear is both a condition and a control spell. So condition removals and reduction in condition duration. Making whirl attacks and light field, with stability very powerful in negating a Necro's fears.

Answer (score 1):

Stability simply makes you ignore effects that makes you unable to fight. This includes: knockdown, knockback, stun, dazzle, fear (and I'm not sure of paralyze... have to check this); regardless of their source.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, stability prevents the following effects:

- Daze
- fear
- Float
- Knockback
- Knockdown
- Launch
- Pull
- Sink
- Stun
- Petrified
- Ice block

In other words, the effects that prevent\affect movement. While stability alone does not cancel such effects, various skill may make it so it does.

You can read for yourself here: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Control_effect